# I2C Master send reset command to the slave counter

Tags: c++, i2c

My name is Gianni, I live in Olbia Sardinia Italy and I have some experience in electronics.

For several years I have been passionate about Arduino.

They are now engaged in a project to counter with hall sensors.

The slave sends data to the master via I2C, for my project. I'm using the [sketch of Gammon](http://www.gammon.com.au/i2c) which uses a structure enum to send a request to the slave.

I have the need to send a reset command from master to slave.

I edited the sketch and I can see the command on the slave but will not let me use it to reset the counter.

---

### Master code section

```
   void RstCounter() 
  {

  Serial.println ("funzione azzera attivata");  
   Serial.println (sensor);
  char key = keypad.getKey();   
  if (key !='A')  
  {

   char cmdrst = 'a';
   //set=key; 

     if (sensor==11)
    {
    sendCommand (CMD_WRITE_D2, 1);

    Wire.beginTransmission(SLAVE_ADDRESS); // testiamo questa istruzione
    Wire.write(cmdrst);    
    Wire.endTransmission();

    delay(100);
    Serial.println (cmdrst);  
    }

   else 
  {
  m=0;
  }

   azzera =true; 
  }
   else if (key=='A') 
    { 
   Serial.println("");
   Serial.println("AZZERA close");
   azzera = false;
   }
     delay(100);
    }
```

---

### SLAVE code section

```
#include <Wire.h>

const byte MY_ADDRESS = 42; // address in valore esadecimale

/************  VARIABILI SENSORI **********************/

#define Sensor11 2  
int lastValueSensor11 =0;
int ValueSensor11=0;
int contatore11=0;
int counter11;



// various commands we might get
/************  VARIABILI ENUMERATORE **********************/
enum {
    CMD_ID = 1,
    CMD_READ_D2  = 2,
    CMD_READ_D3 = 3,
    CMD_READ_D4 = 4,
    CMD_WRITE_D2 = 5
    };

char command;
int sensor;
char cmdrst;

/************  SETUP **********************/
void setup() 
  {
  command = 0;

  pinMode (Sensor11, INPUT);
  digitalWrite (Sensor11, HIGH);  // enable pull-up

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin (MY_ADDRESS);
  Wire.onReceive (receiveEvent);  // interrupt handler for incoming messages
  Wire.onRequest (requestEvent);  // interrupt handler for when data is wanted

  }  // end of setup

/************  LOOP **********************/
void loop() 
  {
        /************************ CONTATORE SENSOR 1 ***********************/
   ValueSensor11  = digitalRead(Sensor11); 

            if ( ValueSensor11 != lastValueSensor11) 
               { if ( ValueSensor11 == LOW)
                    { 
                      contatore11 = contatore11 + 1; 

                        }
                     }
   lastValueSensor11 = ValueSensor11;



/************  I2C RECEIVE **********************/
void receiveEvent (int howMany)
  {

  command = Wire.read ();  // remember command for when we get request
  //Serial.println(command);
  switch (command)
     {
     case CMD_WRITE_D2:  
     Serial.println("comando 5 ricevuto");     
     char cmdrst=Wire.read();
     delay(100);        
     Serial.println (cmdrst);
     break;
    }
} // end of receiveEvent


void sendSensor1 (const byte which)
  {
  int val11 = contatore11;
  Serial.println(contatore11);
  byte buf11 [2];

    buf11 [0] = val11 >> 8;
    buf11 [1] = val11 & 0xFF;
    Wire.write (buf11, 2);
  }  // end of sendSensor



void requestEvent ()
  {
  switch (command)
     {
     case CMD_ID:       
     Wire.write (0x55); 
     break;   // send our ID 


     case CMD_READ_D2:  
     sendSensor1 (2);    
     break;  // send A0 value


     case CMD_READ_D3:  
     sendSensor2 (3); 
     break;    // send D8 value


     case CMD_READ_D4:  
     sendSensor3 (4); 
     break;

     }  // end of switch

  }  // end of requestEvent
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void receiveEvent (int howMany)
  {

  command = Wire.read ();  // remember command for when we get request
  //Serial.println(command);
  switch (command)
     {
     case CMD_WRITE_D2:  
     Serial.println("comando 5 ricevuto");     
     char cmdrst=Wire.read();
     delay(100);        
     Serial.println (cmdrst);
     break;
    }
} // end of receiveEvent
```

- Don't do serial prints inside an interrupt service routine (ISR). That is, not here.
- Don't do `delay` inside an ISR.

---

```
  if (key !='A')  
  {
```

I would be checking for NO_KEY first, otherwise you will assume that no key press is not 'A' and be doing that transmission to the slave **a lot**.

Comment: Was the answer helpful? If so, please [accept](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it by clicking on the "tick" icon next to the answer, and also possibly [upvote](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it. This indicates to other users that you found the answer useful, and it also stops Stack Exchange from periodically "bumping" your question in the hope of getting an accepted answer. Thanks for your understanding and cooperation!